# Disabling CoW eventually leads user to break BTRFS snapshot references

Tags: backup, btrfs, snapshot

In the following scenario, user willl have to break his/her own snapshot references:

1. You have multiple disks (A, B, C, D) with a size of 1 TB and it's filled by 800 GB of data. You also have multiple virtual machines, which has a size of 400GB.
2. You are keeping your Btrfs snapshot copies on multiple different disks (B, C, and D) by using `btrfs send | btrfs receive`.
3. Your current disk (A) has errors so you needed to boot from your second disk (B).

Now you have to manually set `No CoW` on some folders, especially for some database folders (like `~/.config/chromium`) and the virtual machine folders.

In order to do that,

1. You need to create a new folder
2. Set `chattr +C your-new-vm-folder`
3. **COPY** your current virtual machine files into it.

You may or may not complete this step because you need some free space to perform the copy/delete operations (VM files are large).

Even if you could complete this step, you can not simply keep your VM folder contents by only sending the diffs to your other disks (C and D) because contents are completely changed, so you have to send all of your VM data from start.

How can you keep your NoCow directories in sync still by sending only the diffs (incremental snapshots)?

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to boot from your backup disk, your NoCoW folders will suffer from this problem.

Comment: Your own question is "How can you keep your NoCow directories in sync still by sending only the diffs (incremental snapshots)?". I don't see how this "answer" answers it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I came across with this problem and I wanted to express it. The answer can not solve this problem currently but is valid and says "this issue can not be solved at this moment".